Is this concrete or a natural stone?
I have a sewer pipe the passes through a creek (marked with a white arrow). On the upstream side, there's something that looks either like a natural formation, or some kind of concrete (circled in white).
If it's the former, then I should remove it as it's blocking water from going under the pipe. The water ends up going over the pipe which disrupts the landscaping and the hardscaping upstream and downstream from the pipe.
If it's the latter, it looks like it was specifically meant to prevent water from going under it and rather to force it to go above it. Why would that be the goal?
Finally, please note that I broke off a small piece of it and you can see it sitting on top of the formation, and a close up in the second picture



could be sandstone ... doesn't quite look like concrete

I'd be slightly concerned about why the pipe is visible at all?  Shouldn't it be completely buried under the creek?

I'm very concerned. But what can I do now?

Looks like concrete, probably meant to encase the sewer pipe, but there has been erosion in the stream and the concrete is exposed and has weathered.

Yes it's probably concrete. You should probably leave it there as you don't want water to go under the pipe because that may erode whatever is supporting it, which then may lead to breakage and failure of the pipe.
